# Reading object directly from AWS S3 bucket and return workbook using SpreadsheetGear

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3, spreadsheetgear

An excel file can be downloaded from S3 to web-server and then can be populated in a Spreadsheetgear workbook object. However, I am trying to read an array of bytes or streams from an excel file stored in an S3 bucket and populate a workbook object.

Answer (score 0):

Got exactly what I needed :

```
 public static SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook GetObjectFromS3AndReturnWorkbook(string key, string path, string bucketName)
        {
            GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(bucketName, key);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
            {
                responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            }
            IWorkbookSet workbookSet = Factory.GetWorkbookSet();
            SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook workbook = workbookSet.Workbooks.OpenFromStream(memoryStream);
            return workbook;
        }
```